# Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Tags: swift, enums

i'm trying to create array form typealias, the second parameter is need to be of type enum.

```
enum PainLevel : String {
        case none = "None"
        case mid = "Mid"
        case moderate = "Moderate"
        case severe = "Severe"  
}

typealias SymptomQuestion = (subject : String, value : Any)

let symptomQuestions : [SymptomQuestion] = [
   SymptomQuestion("Headache Level",Symptom.PainLevel)
]
```

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name .
>
> Add arguments
>   after the type to construct a value of the type.
>
> Use '.self' to
>   reference the type object

Why do i need to add self / Add arguments after the type to construct?
I just want to use the type of the enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `PainLevel` you need to specify its specific case that you have declared with your `enum`. So change `Symptom.PainLevel` with `Symptom.PainLevel.none` or any other case like `mid`, `moderate` and `severe`.

```
let symptomQuestions : [SymptomQuestion] = [
    SymptomQuestion("Headache Level", Symptom.PainLevel.none)
]
```

**Edit:** As `Hamish` suggested you can also use `.self` with `PainLevel` but better option is to use enum's `case` instead of self because that will give you idea what is the `PainLevel` case.

```
let symptomQuestions : [SymptomQuestion] = [
    SymptomQuestion("Headache Level", Symptom.PainLevel.self)
]
```

Comment: There is no way to use only the type of the enum? If I don't want to provide any default value

Comment: @Maor No thats not possible.

Comment: @Maor As the error message says, you use postfix `.self` to refer to the metatype of the enum – `Symptom.PainLevel.self`.